# Use Breadth First method to print both the path and the content each node line by line

Tags: java, data-structures, encoding, file-handling, decision-tree

I have a decision tree that looks like :

Root: a

Level 1: b, c

Level 2: d, e, f, g

I would like to write a file and save the tree in this format:

```
a

Y b

N c

YY d

YN e

NY f

NN g
```

Currently, I am using a queue for the content of the nodes. I think I also need a queue for the string variables, but I don't really know how to do that. Could some one help me with that? How could I write out the the path and the content line by line?

```
public void saveTree(){
    Queue<Tree> contentQueue = new LinkedList<Tree>();
    Queue<String> pathQueue = new LinkedList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
    contentQueue.add(this);
    while(!contentQueue.isEmpty()){
        Tree child = (tree) contentQueue.remove();
        output.add(child.getData());
        if(child.getLeft() != null){
            contentQueue.add(child.getLeft());
            }
        if(child.getLeft()!= null){
            contentQueue.add(child.getRight());
            }
    }
```

Comment: Which data structure stores your decision tree (the tree that needs to be written to a file)?

Comment: My tree extends the Binary Tree class.

Comment: Which variable in the code you included stores your decision tree?

Comment: The saveTree is stored in my Tree class. In the code, this represents my decision tree. Tree class has other methods like  constructors, getters and setters.

Comment: What would getData return for the root node?  What do you mean by "the string variables"?

Comment: getData will return the content of each node: like a, b, c ,d etc. For string variables, I mean Y, N, YY, YN etc

Comment: Where are the string variables associated with each node in the tree stored?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of this simple method:

```
public void saveTree(){
    Queue<Tree> contentQueue = new LinkedList<Tree>();
    Queue<String> pathQueue = new LinkedList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
    contentQueue.add(this);
    pathQueue,add("");     //use the queue of string side-by-side
    while(!contentQueue.isEmpty()){
        Tree child = (Tree) contentQueue.remove();
        String val = pathQueue.remove();
        output.add(val + " " + child.getData());
        if(child.getLeft() != null){
            contentQueue.add(child.getLeft());
            pathQueue.add(val + "Y");     //concatenate the current value to the parent value
            }
        if(child.getRight()!= null){
            contentQueue.add(child.getRight());
            pathQueue.add(val + "N");     //concatenate the current value to the parent value
            }
    }
```